# Can not find LLVM library files

Tags: include, llvm

I have been trying to set up llvm on my linux. I am running fedora. I have tried installing llvm through dnf install llvm and it appears to be installed on my computer. However, in my c++ code any header I try to include from it shows error. I am currently trying to do it manually but if you have any answers I would be grateful if you share it with me. Thanks.

Comment: Which of the header files are you unable to find?? Have you taken a look at you include directory??

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following commands to find where are the include directory and LLVM libraries in your Linux system. Then they can be included into your compilation command.

```
llvm-config --includedir
llvm-config --libfiles
```

I don't use Fedora, but in my Linux Mint 20, these commands return:

```
/usr/lib/llvm-10/include
/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/libLLVM-10.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to install `llvm-devel`:

```
dnf install llvm-devel
```

This will also provide the `llvm-config` binary, which you can confirm with:

```
dnf provides llvm-config
```